# Loading OpenCV dll file to netbeans project

Tags: java, opencv

I tried to add OpenCV library and I even changed the class path and environmental variable even. I followed this tutorial [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE](http://OpenCV)
But i keep getting the following error.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\opencv\build\java\x86\opencv_java300.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll
>   on a AMD 64-bit platform

I have used x64 folder in definning class path. But in the above error it's directed to x86 folder. I can't figure out the reason.Please help me.